# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate not updating when using batchUpdate

Tags: java, database

I have a list of objects provided by another service which I use to update my own data. When I try to use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate`, all returned values are zero.

```
public void updateWeather(List<Weather> weatherList) {
    String query = "UPDATE weather \n" +
        "SET rain_probability = ROUND(:rainProbability, 4), \n" +
        "wind_speed = :windSpeed \n" +
        "WHERE city_id = :cityId AND date = :date;";

    List<MapSqlParameterSource> batchList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Weather weather : weatherList) {
        MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        params.addValue("rainProbability", weather.getRainProbability());
        params.addValue("windSpeed", weather.getWindSpeed());
        params.addValue("cityId", weather.getCityId());
        params.addValue("date", weather.getDate());
        batchList.add(params);
    }

    this.namedParameterJdbcParameter
       .batchUpdate(query, batchList.toArray(new MapSqlParameterSource[] {});
}
```

If I run this `UPDATE` directly in the database, it works fine. Futhermore, if I run it one by one, that is, replacing values (instead of adding the parameter source to `batchList`) it also works.

For example:

```
for (Weather weather : weatherList) {
    String query = String.format("UPDATE weather \n" +
        "SET rain_probability = ROUND('%d', 4), \n" +
        " wind_speed = %d \n" +
        " WHERE city_id = :cityId AND date = :date;",
       weather.getRainProbability(),
       weather.getWindSpeed(),
       weather.getCityId(),
       weather.getDate()
    );

   this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(query, Collections.emptyMap());
}
```

Any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the use of "\n" or the ";" at the end of the statement within the String? (I'm surprised you don't get a SQL Syntax exception with the ; inside the actual query string)

Also dates are always a bit tricky and if that isn't converting properly then your WHERE clause isn't going to match and is possibly why 0 rows are returned. Could you temporarily try converting dates to Strings and see if the count is correct (e.g. for Oracle:   AND date = TO_DATE(:dateStr, 'DD/MM/YYYY') )